# ¿Cómo hacer para que las reglas de CSS no se hereden y solo afecten al elemento padre?

Tags: html, css

Buen día, tengo un problemilla...
Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario dentro de una etiqueta section, y esta etiqueta section tiene una transparencia de 0.5 para que se pueda ver la imagen que esta de background en el body.

La cosa es que esa transparencia también se aplica a mi formulario, entonces la imagen del fondo es perceptible pero mi formulario se transparenta también y mi idea es que el formulario tenga una opacidad de 1.

[image: El problema:]

Ya intente cambiar la opacidad del formulario a 1, pero entiendo que como es una etiqueta hija no funciona.

El código es el siguiente (El div contaría como el form, tengo una razón para hacerlo así):

```
<section>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="formulario">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" class="field">
                <br>
            <label for="opciones">Ingresa lo que deseas hacer:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="adoptar" name="opciones" value="adoptar">
            <label for="adoptar">Adoptar una Mascota</label>
                <br>
            </section>
```

El código de CSS:

```
section{
width: 100%;
height: 200rem;
position: relative;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color:aliceblue;}

.formulario{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
font-size: 23px;
border: 3px solid rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Hola bro, busque tu respuesta en internet y encontre algo que te puede ayudar habla sobre el !important. Esta en foros del web: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f53/evitar-herencia-estilo-978538/

Answer (score 0):

No se puede poner opacidad a un elemento padre sin afectar a un elemento hijo, sin embargo, en tu ejemplo que lo puedes hacer es establecer el color del fondo como rgba que acepta transparencia

```css
section{
width: 100%;
height: 200rem;
position: relative;
background-color:rgb(240 248 255 / 50%);
}

.formulario{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
font-size: 23px;
border: 3px solid rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="formulario">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" class="field">
                <br>
            <label for="opciones">Ingresa lo que deseas hacer:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="adoptar" name="opciones" value="adoptar">
            <label for="adoptar">Adoptar una Mascota</label>
                <br>
            </section>
```